# Python: If statements and Scrapy XPath selector

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to select the values contained in the last column of a table at: https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=bmo.TO&a=02&b=2&c=2005&d=02&e=2&f=2015&g=m

Usually, this would be quite simple. Something like:

```
response.xpath('//table//table//tr[::6]/text()').extract()
```

However, the nth element constantly changes due to these dividend rows yahoo chooses to throw in there. However, I noticed that for every row that I want to select the data from, the first td contains:

```
Feb 2, 2015
```

instead of:

```
2015-01-29
```

Therefore, I am trying to build a code that follows the logic where if the first cell of the table contains ANY letters, select the last column and append it to a list. The code I have is below:

```
returns = []
trows = response.xpath('//table//table//tr')
for tr in trows:
      # don't know why I need to use "2" in the following line, but that's what gives me the first value.
    check = response.xpath('//td[2]/text()').extract()
    if any(c.isalpha() for c in check) == True:
        these = tr[6]
        returns.append(these)
```

This contains all sorts of problems though as I am sure you can imagine. It gives me the value of the 1st `td` repeated as many times as there is a `tr` in the table. When the end result that I need is the last `td`.

Very grateful for any help received! I'm trying to do this for a finance class project to learn python instead of inputing the values manually.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check whether the date matches the `%b %d, %Y` format with the help [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) and exception handling. In other words, follow the [`EAFP` principle](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp).

Demo from the [`Scrapy Shell`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html):

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime
In [2]: rows = response.xpath('//table[@class="yfnc_datamodoutline1"]//table/tr')[1:]
In [3]: for row in rows:
            cells = row.xpath('.//td/text()').extract()
            try:
                datetime.strptime(cells[0], "%b %d, %Y")
                print cells[-1]
            except ValueError:
                continue    
77.15
77.46
72.93
81.33
82.99
80.88
...
44.12
42.46
39.00
42.20
```

I've also improved the XPath expressions to focus more on the desired table data.